Undeclared identifier : _requireOwned(tokenId) error
I am getting below error while running the smart contract:
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol:35:9:
|
35 |         _requireOwned(tokenId);
|         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Smart contract code:
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract RealEstate is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721("Real Estate", "REAL") {}

    function mint(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tokenIds.current();
    }
}


I tried removing the _requireOwned(tokenId); from ERC721URIStorage.sol but still getting the error.
Any help would be appreciated.
I tried removing the _requireOwned(tokenId); from ERC721URIStorage.sol but still getting the error.
Also tried adding the _requireOwned(tokenId) into my smart contract but it's throwing same error.

Where are you building the smart contract? - this works fine when pasted and deployed to a VM using Remix (https://remix.ethereum.org). I suspect that whatever way you're building the smart contract is not recognizing and resolving the URL for @openzepplin/. Maybe try the full URL instead ie.
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

